# AngularJS scope variable always undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This might sound like a silly question but I've been stuck on this one for a few hours.  There must be something amazingly simple I'm overlooking.

I've got an ng-repeat directive which is outputting a list of items:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="foo in bars">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

And then inside, at the end of the list I've got a form to add to the list:

```
<div class="add">
    <input ng-model="valueToAdd" class="weight" />
    <a ng-click="addStuff()" class="button-small"> + Add</a>    
</div>
```

The `addStuff()` method is on my controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.addStuff= function () {
        alert($scope.valueToAdd);
    }
}
```

But `$scope.valueToAdd` always gives me `undefined`.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's a punker where this problem is reproduced: http://plnkr.co/edit/YoGdx8?p=preview

Comment: Seems to work just fine ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXc5ygyqXiKH9Fi1N9gd?p=preview))

Comment: Hmm ok.  Let me take a second look.  Could be something outside of the code I copy/pasted as an example.  Typical ;-)

Comment: maybe valueToAdd is outside the scope of MyCtrl

Comment: @Atrix1987 good call, I figured it wouldn't be but it might :)

Comment: Hi guys, just added a link to a plunker (I forked your plunker @robertklep and modified so it's more similar to my actual code and now I have the same problem there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates new scope for each of its repeated sections and so `valueToAdd` is bound to a variable on that inner scope, which is a child of the outer scope. When `addStuff` is called, it works because it accesses the method on the outer scope via scope inheritance, but the variable it tries to reference is not defined in that outer scope.

Try passing the value to `addStuff` instead:

```
ng-click="addStuff(valueToAdd)"
```

[Here is a forked Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/A5r8jl?p=preview)

Comment: BINGO!  That makes a whole lot of sense.  Thanks!